# Building struct to varying json provided by an API

Tags: json, go

I'm building a discord bot capable of reading Tibia's API. 
I'm facing one problem though. 
Part of the json given by the api is this:

`"account_information":{"loyalty_title":"Warden of Tibia","created":{"date":"2012-11-08 18:26:35.000000","timezone_type":2,"timezone":"CET"}}`

But, players can choose to hide this information, and when it is so, the json looks like this: `"account_information":[]`

So, as you can see, sometimes its an empty array, sometimes its a struct. 
I have made this struct:

```
type ActInfo struct {
    LoyaltyTitle string `json:"loyalty_title"`
    Created      struct {
        Date         string `json:"date"`
        TimezoneType int    `json:"timezone_type"`
        Timezone     string `json:"timezone"`
    } `json:"created"`
}
```

But, when I search for a character that has this information hidden, it errors out.

Basically: `type ActInfo struct` works for when the information is not hidden, and `type ActInfo []struct` works for when the information is shown. But they error out to each other.

If I change it all to:

```
AccountInformation json.RawMessage `json:"account_information"`
```

It works for all cases, but then Im not sure how to grab the information anymore later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [json.Unmarshaler](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface on the `*ActInfo`. 
Unmarshal the JSON to a struct if the JSON is an object (starts with "{").

```
func (ai *ActInfo) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if bytes.HasPrefix(data, []byte("{")) {
        type actInfoNoMethods ActInfo
        return json.Unmarshal(data, (*actInfoNoMethods)(ai))
    } 
    return nil
}
```

To prevent recursive calls to UnnmarshalJSON, the function declares type `actInfoNoMethods` with the same underlying struct declaration as `ActInfo`.  The method receiver is [converted](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to a `*actInfoNoMethods` for the call to json.Unmarshal.

Because the UnmarshalJSON method in this answer unnmarshals directly to an `ActInfo` value, there's no need to update the UnmarshalJSON method when fields are added or removed from `ActInfo`.

The method in this answer returns `nil` if the JSON is not an object. Depending on your needs, you can to report an error if the JSON is not an empty array, set a field indicating no value, etc.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/URDzf3OxJ1D).

Answer (score 1):

If a field is returned as both an array and an object, then you don't have much choice. You either have to unmarshal it to an interface{} and deal with it, or use json.RawMessage. With json.RawMessage, you can do:

```
var acct AccountInformation
if len(data.accountInformation)>0 && data.accountInformation[0]=='{' {
   json.Unmarshal(data.accountInformation,&acct)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom JSON unmarshaler:

```
func (a *ActInfo) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
  type actInfo ActInfo
  var tmp actInfo
  if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &tmp); err != nil {
     if e, ok := err.(*json.UnmarshalTypeError); !ok || e.Value != "array" {
         return err
     }
  }
  a.LoyaltyTitle = tmp.LoyaltyTitle
  a.Created = tmp.Created
  return nil
}
```

And then you can just Unmarshal like normal and it should just work.

https://play.golang.org/p/oeT3BYhcGXn